# Salesforce server IP which is making callout

Tags: apex, batch, httprequest, http

I have a batch process which makes a HTTP call out to third party, but because of IP restriction third party is denaying the request.

Is there any way to get Salesforce server Client IP from where this callout is making?

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce publishes the [IP ranges](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003652&type=1) for their networks.

They recommend whitelisting the entire range set:

> Please be reminded that our best practice and recommendation is to whitelist the entire list of Salesforce IP ranges for seamless access.

Since your Salesforce org does not have its own static IP and can change instance.

Comment: Okay, but is there a way to get the IP to check location from where the request is going from ?

Comment: @Harry make a callout to this endpoint https://putsreq.com to see from which IP the call orignated

Comment: Like Pranay said, but you cannot assume that all callouts made from Salesforce will come from that IP address permanently.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce does not have static IP address and hence you have to whitelist all IP's which are mentioned in this link.

Src : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003652&type=1